# Angular Checkbox doesn't change color of a div

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and facing a problem. What I'm doing is i created an `app` component and inside its template there is `div` containing `checkbox` and `label`, `ts` file of that component has an array of strings and boolean variable. Using `ngFor` directive on one `div` and iterating through strings of array and printing element value inside label. Also every `div` has an `ngClass` directive which has an expression of boolean variable and apply `css` class when variable is true. Boolean variable is only true when we check that checkbox and it's change background color of that div. But Why it's not change background color of that specific div that is checked, It changed color of all `divs`. I only want to change color of that `div` which is only checked.

Code:
`src/app.ts`

```
@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 template: `
  <div class="myDiv" *ngFor = "let elm of my_Arr" [ngClass]={changeClass:state}>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkdemo" (change)="state=!state">
  <label for="checkdemo">{{elm}}</label>

</div>

 `,
 styles: [`

 .myDiv {
 background-color : white;
 border:1px solid black;
}

.changeClass {
  background-color : red;
}

 `]
})
export class App {
 private state = false;
 private my_Arr: string[] = ['string 1', 'string 2'];
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

See [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/bDFQfuDfzWCFMZlax6qf?p=preview)

Comment: i created one plunker [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/0cjerYbjEMhUIia2UPlS?p=preview)it may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are binding all `div`'s `ngClass` with the same `state` and also to checkboxes, when any of those checkboxes value changed will effect all `div`'s style.

and the solution should be change `state` to an `array`, and bind element of the array to `ngClass` and checkbox.

see **[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/AiwktCAJT90dZUB9LWK0?p=preview)**